# Installer encountered error copying files to hard disk while installing ubuntu on Windows hosted virtual box

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox, ssd, windows-10

While trying to run a Ubuntu-based virtual machine for windows host PC. I am running into the problem "installer encountered error copying files to hard disk". The downloaded `ISO` image matches the `md5sum`. Summarizing the details below:

Configuration:
 - SSD: Samsung SSD 970 EVO Plus 500 GB
 - Virtual box version: 6.1
 - Ubuntu images tried: 16.04.6 LTS (Xenial Xerus), Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS (Bionic Beaver)
 - VM config: 
    - RAM: 6 GB out of 16GB
    - Disk: 60 GB out of 500 GB

6 GB out of 16 GB, 60 GB out of 500 GB)

[image: Screenshot]